# Why use superflous dash (-) to pass option flags to tar?

Tags: utilities, tar

To create a tar file for a directory, the `tar` command with `compress`, `verbose` and `file` options can be typed thus:

```
$ tar -cvf my.tar my_directory/
```

But it also works to do it this way:

```
 $ tar cvf my.tar my_directory/
```

That is, without the dash (-) preceding the options. Why would you ever pass a dash (-) to the option list?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28403/tar-cvf-or-tar-cvf

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There are several different patterns for options that have been used historically in UNIX applications.  Several old ones, like *tar*, use a positional scheme:

> *command options arguments*

as for example tar uses

> tar *something*f *"file operated on"* *"paths of files to manipulate"*

In a first attempt to avoid the confusion, *tar* and a few other programs with the old flags-arguments style allowed delimiting the flags with dashes, but most of us old guys simply ignored that.

Some other commands have a more complicated command line syntax, like *dd(1)* which uses flags, equal signs, pathnames, arguments and a partridge in a pear tree, all with wild abandon.

In BSD and later versions of unix, this had more or less converged to single-character flags marked with '-', but this began to present a couple of problems:

- the flags could be hard to remember
- sometimes you actually wanted to use a name with '-'
- and especially with GNU tools, there began to be limitations imposed by the number of possible flags.  So GNU tools added GNU long options like `--output`.

Then Sun decided that the extra '-' was redundant and started using long-style flags with single '-'s.

And that's how it came to be the mess it is now.

Comment: *"and a partridge in a pear tree"* Better than my dry attempt. You win.

Comment: nice historical context.

Comment: I notice that a lot of X programs (including, say, X, from Xorg), use long-style flags with a single `-`. Is that from Sun?

Comment: You've also missed an important step: before inventing GNU style options with "--", Posix.2 specified to use "-W" for the same goal and this was supported by several Unix flavors. GNU getopt allows them in parallel if add "W;" to its option string, but two-hyphen style is recommended which is easier to read.

Comment: Hm, the only place I've ever seen that is -W arguments for gcc warnings.

Comment: Note that [Guideline 4](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) of POSIX standard (chapter [12.2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) of [POSIX IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 Edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX.1-2008_.28with_one_TC.29)) requires `-` delimiter character. Quote: *All options should be preceded by the '-' delimiter character.*

Comment: What is the meanig of ‘partridge in a pear tree’? (Can I have any useful & easy-to-understand link?)

Comment: @plhn Idiom. A traditional English Christmas carol "The Twelve Days of Christmas" lists a whole bunch of extravagant gifts, ending with "a partridge in a pear tree". It suggests a long extravagant list.

Comment: Another old one which doesn't use dashes is `dd`. All of its arguments are optional, using `key=val` syntax. Since `dd`'s arguments don't have to be distinguished from non-optionals, they don't have a leading dash.

Comment: dd(1) is an excellent example.

Comment: @patryk.beza it's a little late but notice that tar and those other old commands still ignore POSIX.

Comment: @CharlieMartin: Arguments like `-Wall` are actually shortcuts for `-W=all` in (POSIX?) argument formats

Comment: @0xLogN 50 years of grad students have demolished the standards.

Comment: @CharlieMartin yeah, its really annoying.

Answer (score 10):

You can give tar options in the standard unix manner `tar -c -f foo -v -B file1 file2 file3` where you need the dash to differentiate between options and parameters or the file names at the end of the command line.  Or you can put all the options together in the first argument, in which case the dash is optional.

Then there is `ps`, where you use the dashes if you're using the SysV-ish options, and leave them out if you're using BSD-ish options, just to make things more confusing.

And lets not even talk about `find`.

Answer (score 2):

The dash is used in order to disambiguate between an option parameter names and values. I guess it's more of a standard convention.

Comment: I was going to add the `best-practice` tag because I thought it may come down to that.

Comment: @Milktrader, it's a difficult question when talking about best practices. Following standard conventions is indeed best practice, but whether you want to do it in your cases it's not clear. It will depend on your scenario. If you are hacking some quick command in the shell you probably wouldn't care much about it but if you are writing a library it is important to follow well established conventions because you don't have control of how this library is going to be used by clients. In this case you should cover all possible cases and disambiguating between option names and values is important.

Answer (score -1):

With leading minus/dash sign (-) you need to keep the options in accurate order. Without minus order of your option can change.

For example:

```
# tar -xvf yourfile.tar
# tar vxf yourfile.tar
```

Comment: This answer is half right, but AFAIK it's only flags like `f` that take an argument whose order matters. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239120/3169

Comment: Thanks upvoting. The mention of `order` is very helpful now I understand.