# tar cvf or tar -cvf?

Tags: tar, options, portability

I have learned to use tar without '-' for options, like `tar cvfz dir.tar.gz Directory/` but I recently came accross the slightly different `tar -czvf` syntax (I think the 'f' must be the last option in this case).

Both work on linux and Mac OS. Is there a recommended syntax, with or without '-', which is more portable accross unix flavors?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13573/why-use-superflous-dash-to-pass-option-flags-to-tar

Comment: The reason why `-f` must be the last option is because it takes an argument and that argument may be given touching the option. `tar -cvfz dir.tar.gz Directory` means to create an archive named `z` that contains the files `dir.tar.gz` and `Directory`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`tar` is one of those ancient commands from the days when option syntax hadn't been standardized. Because all useful invocations of `tar` require specifying an operation before providing any file name, most `tar` implementations interpret their first argument as an option even if it doesn't begin with a `-`. Most current implementations accept a `-`; the only exception that I'm aware of is [Minix](http://www.minix3.org/manpages/man1/tar.1.html).

Older versions of POSIX and Single Unix included a `tar` command with no `-` before the operation specifier. Single Unix v2 had both traditional archivers [`cpio`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/cpio.html) and [`tar`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/tar.html), but very few flags could be standardized because existing implementations were too different, so the standards introduced a new command, [`pax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/pax.html), which is the only standard archiver in since [Single Unix v3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html). If you want standard compliance, use `pax`, but beware that many Linux distributions don't include it in their base installation, and there's no `pax` in [Minix](http://www.minix3.org/manpages/). If you want portability in practice, use `tar cf filename.tar`.

Comment: [newer version of the pax specification (POSIX:2008)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html)

Comment: Also note that if a Linux distro contains `pax`, it usually comes with the worst known pax implementation (GNU pax) that should be avoided because of many bugs.

Comment: Also, the `ps` command has the same behavior, you may omit the `-` for the options.

Comment: @perror That's wrong. Many versions of `ps` don't let you omit the `-`. The Linux version has options with and without `-`, but most have different meanings (BSD vs System V compatibility).

Comment: It is true that, most of the time, I only use `ps aux`... So, I might be (partly) wrong. Sorry.

Comment: So going forward, and to plainly answer Gilles question. Yes, the recommended, now standardized, and good practice format now would include the - before the options whether its needed or not.

Comment: Looks like `pax` is part of MINIX [since v3.1.2a](https://github.com/Stichting-MINIX-Research-Foundation/minix/commit/bea0bcc2ebf960ab00dbf0a0ac7c50a0c1e13418), released in 2009, but the man page was added later [in v3.1.7](https://github.com/Stichting-MINIX-Research-Foundation/minix/commit/4cb358d9992fee69eed3d50816e162446dd70092#diff-b047cc0d695377243c6d7697288331071bb3482c2b586b7d29f4d6ebbeb46ef0), released in 2010.

Answer (score 13):

I may be a dinosaur, but I think that habitually using `cvf` instead of `-cvf` is probably more portable.  I imagine most Linux distros use GNU tar, and I would guess that the *BSDs do also, but you'll find proprietary Unixes that still use the old SysV tar, which used to *require* you to not use a `-` in the options.

I do not use `-cvf` (or `-xf` or whatever) and I have no trouble even with bleeding edge Arch linux.

And just as a side note, I think you can use the Sun-standard `jar` command options with or without a `-` as well.

Comment: I agree with your answer, even if the info page of tar (which is very clear about the three styles of specifying options) tells that old options are kept only for compatibility and there are a bunch of options that have NO old correspondence.

Comment: You are wrong: tar on AT&T UNIX was written not to have a - but it accepts the - and skips it. The only portable way to call tar is to call it without the - and if you ever find a "tar" implementation that does not accept things without -, this is not tar.

Comment: @schily maybe you misread the answer, because even though you use the obnoxious "You are wrong" prefix, your statement about no dash being more portable is exactly what this answer already says.

Answer (score 3):

There have been few programs on UNIX that do not follow the current option standard.

One is `dd`, but dd was derived from the IBM mainframe program `DDR` (Disk Dump and Restore).

One is `ar` and the other is `tar`. From my information, tar wanted to be similar to ar.

All tar implementations work without the - and no useful implementation requires the -. So if you like to write portable scripts, check the SUSv2 standard and only use a commandline that is compatible to SUSv2.