# difference between tar -xzf and tar xjf ? How do we determine that what combination should be used in order to extract something(.tar)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar, command

While extracting a file with extension `.gz` we used tar `-xzf` and while extracting a file with extension `.bz2` we used `-xjf`. What's the difference between these?

Sometimes the combination used is `-tf`, `-xf` etc and many more. How to determine which combination should be used with which kind of file?
It maybe a basic question but I need an explanation regarding the same.

Comment: I advise a question at a time. A good starting point is reading the man page of `tar` https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar .  Having or not the "-" is for historical reasons, `z` is for gzipped and `j`
 is for bzipped tar(red) files.

Comment: I read the same but wasnt able to get things . And what do you mean by "historical reasons"?

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28403/tar-cvf-or-tar-cvf   explains the optional hyphen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The generic answer for "how to determine" is to read the [manual page for `tar`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) by issuing the command `man tar` on your system.  (The linked page is *a* manual page for `tar`, but by issuing the command on your system you'll ensure you have the manual page for the version you are currently using.)

From the manual page you'll see that the `z` option causes the file(s) to be filtered through `gzip`, which by convention have the extension `.tar.gz` or `.tgz`, while the `j` option causes the file to be filtered through bzip2.

Versions of [GNU `tar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) since 1.15 (2004-12-21) autodetect common compression methods, so neither the `j` nor the `z` will be necessary on linux distributions of the last decade or so.  `tar xf ...` will untar a file whether it is an uncompressed archive, a `gzip`-compressed archive, a `bzip2`-compressed archive, or several other formats.  Other unix or unix-like systems (or linux distributions which don't use GNU tools ?) may not have this shortcut available.

---

As to the secondary question, the `t` option request only listing the files in the archive, while the `x` option actually extracts the files.

Comment: Would you please add the context of that question of  "-"/historical reasons - BSD vs Sys V? `tar` should be one of the most ancient utilities around the block I suspect.

Comment: Still did not got how to form those combinations and how to deal with that "-" ??

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, perhaps I can expand.  I suspect this can be closed as a duplicate instead; I'm sure I've seen similar questions with the history of the different option formats already explained.

Comment: @user4556274 Most probably, I noticed that too but have not searched. The OP is also asking too basic questions.

Comment: @Maniraj You have got to experiment and read a lot about it. Only asking here wont cut it.

Comment: Have my +1 too for the effort.

Comment: user4556274 : »» Recent versions «« : Automatic recognition of .gz, .bz2 → tar version 1.15 - Sergey Poznyakoff, **2004**-12-20 .  Automatic recognition of .zx : Year 2009.

Comment: @KnudLarsen, thank you; updated answer to reflect your comment, with caveat about systems which have non-GNU versions of `tar`.

Comment: @Maniraj You know, ideally this site should be for questions not easily researched. In this case, to learn how to deal with the `-`, you can follow the link given to you: "GNU tar" > "Documentation for Tar" > "HTML" (any is good) > "Invoking GNU tar" > "The Three Option Styles" > "Old Option Style"

Comment: For all those saying RT*M (or a variant of it): According to Google, this answer is a lot more helpful than 'man tar', it's the very first result when searching for "tar xjf".