# Does parameter order matter with tar?

Tags: linux, tar, parameter

I am learning Linux.  I was surprised to see that the parameter order seems to matter when making a tarball.

```
tar -cfvz casual.tar.gz snapback.txt bucket.txt
```

gives the error:

```
tar: casual.tar.gz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

But if I issue the command like this:

```
tar -cvzf casual.tar.gz snapback.txt bucket.txt
```

the tarball is created without errors

Can anyone explain to me why the parameter order matters in this example or where I can find that information to learn why myself?  I tried it the way I did in my first example that received an error with the logic of putting the required parameters c and f first followed by my other parameters.

I want to completely absorb Linux, which includes understanding why things like this occur.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Obligatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1168/)

Comment: In general, you can use the parameters of most commands in any order, but if a parameter expects some value, you have to give that value to the right parameter. The `f` stands for file, and expects you to give it some filename. Assume you want to also give the `H` parameter, to set the format. Out of `tar -c -H pax -f my.pax file`, `tar -cH my.pax -f pax file`, `tar -cHf my.pax pax file`, `tar -cHf pax my.pax file` etc. only one is really clear. But if you just switch position like `tar -cf my.pax -H pax file` it is equaly clear and valid. Just switch position of the arguments too!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Whether the order matters depends on whether you start the options with a minus

```
$ tar -cfvz casual.tar.gz snapback.txt bucket.txt
tar: casual.tar.gz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

$ tar cfvz casual.tar.gz snapback.txt bucket.txt
snapback.txt
bucket.txt
```

This unusual behavior is documented in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html)

```
 Options to GNU tar can be given in three different styles.
 In traditional style
 ...
 Any command line words that remain after all options has
 been processed are treated as non-optional arguments: file or archive
 member names.
 ...
 tar cfv a.tar /etc
 ...
 In UNIX or short-option style, each option letter is prefixed with a
 single dash, as in other command line utilities.  If an option takes
 argument, the argument follows it, either as a separate command line
 word, or immediately following the option.
 ...
 tar -cvf a.tar /etc
 ...
 In GNU or long-option style, each option begins with two dashes and
 has a meaningful name
 ...
 tar --create --file a.tar --verbose /etc
```

`tar`, which is short for "tape archive" has been around before the current conventions were decided on, so it keeps the different modes for compatibility.

So to "absorb Linux", I'd suggest a few starting lessons:

- always read the man page
- minor differences in syntax are sometimes important

  - the position of items - most commands require options to be the first thing after the command name
  - whether a minus is required (like `tar`, `ps` works differently depending on whether there is a minus at the start)
  - whether a space is optional, required, or must not be there (`xargs -ifoo` is different from `xargs -i foo`)
- some things don't work the way you'd expect

To get the behavior you want in the usual style, put the output file name directly after the `f` or `-f`, e.g.

```
$ tar -cvzf casual.tar.gz snapback.txt bucket.txt
snapback.txt
bucket.txt
```

or:

```
$ tar -c -f casual.tar.gz -z -v snapback.txt bucket.txt
```

or you could use the less common but easier to read GNU long style:

```
$ tar --create --verbose -gzip --file casual.tar.gz snapback.txt bucket.txt
```

Answer (score 9):

Checking the `-f` option in the tar man page gives us:

> ```
>  -f, --file ARCHIVE
>        use archive file or device ARCHIVE
> ```

That means that the next word that follows the `-f` option is going to be the file's name. In your example, after the `-f` it follows the letters `vz`, which are going to be used as the file's name.

After that it parses every argument as its input to compress into the file now called `vz`. When it tries to do so, `tar` notices that there is no file with the name `casual.tar.gz` to compress, and then it gives your error.

Therefore, after the `-f`, it must always follow the name of the file that you want to produce.

Comment: So I could have used the other parameters in any order, I just need to make sure when I use the f parameter I use it last with my tarball filename directly thereafter.  Correct?

Comment: @BitBug In the most common calling convention, yes, put the `f` as the last letter in your options block.

Comment: If you use the options with the `-` prefixed, the `f` must be the last, the parameters that don't need any argument can be used in any order. Alternatively you could simply not write the `-`.

Comment: But note that this possibility to not need the dash prefix is a `tar`'s particularity, most unix tools won't allow that.